# XSLT is dumping all source XML. Why?

Tags: xml, xslt

VERY basic xslt question. I'm trying to get xslt to format a subset of source xml but all the xml is getting displayed and I have no idea why.

here is xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="XSLTDC.xsl"?>
<letter xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">   
    <title>Letter from Lionel Cary to Loretta Cary</title>  
    <date>07-05-1906</date> 
    <source>        
        <university>UCLA</university>       
        <library>Powell Library</library>       
        <department>Special Collections and University Archives</department>        
    </source>           
</letter>
```

here's xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"    
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml"/>
    <xsl:template match="letter/title">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am getting this:

```
Letter from Lionel Cary to Loretta Cary 07-05-1906 
UCLA Powell Library Special Collections and University Archives
```

but my desired result is this:

```
Letter from Lionel Cary to Loretta Cary
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why this happens is that your only template is matching`title`, leaving the [built-in templates](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#built-in-rule) to process the `letter` node and its other descendants. The effect of this is to copy all text nodes.

To fix this, change your template to:

```
<xsl:template match="/letter">
    <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
</xsl:template>
```